# InvokeOnMainThread() not necessarily invoking on main thread - bug or feature?

Tags: multithreading, timer, mono, xamarin.ios, ui-thread

I'm using a `Timer` and let it perform regular checks. If the test condition is true, I start a thread and let it do what it has to do.

If within that thread I want to change the UI I'm using `InvokeOnMainThread()`. But as the thread was triggered from a `Timer` which already is a seprate thread, the `InvokeOnMainThread()` will invoke things on the Timer's thread and not on the real main thread. I work around it by boxing two `InvokeOnMainThread()` calls.

Is this working as intended or is it a bug in the Mono framework?
Is the main thread defined as the one who triggered the current thread or is it supposed to return the "root" thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSObject.InvokeOnMainThread` is, mostly, a wrapper around [performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Quote from documentation:

> You can use this method to deliver messages to the main thread of your application. The main thread encompasses the application’s main run loop, and is where the NSApplication object receives events.

We can have a deeper look into it (seems weird) if you fill a bug report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com along with a self-contained test case.

Comment: Yes, I will provide something.

Comment: Bug closed, everything is fine :-)